# Are there other theories (apart from string theory) that combined with inflation, would produce universes with different laws?

Tags: string-theory, symmetry, cosmological-inflation, multiverse, laws-of-physics

In chaotic inflation, space would stop expanding in some points, creating hubble volumes that could experience different spontaneous symmetry breaking, which would result in different properties, such as different physical constants or different effective laws.

However, when string theory is combined with inflation, universes with fundamental different laws of physics (not just different effective laws) could be produced.

But apart from string theory, are there any theories that combined with inflation could produce also universes with fundamentally different laws?

Can inflation be applied or be compatible with every single theoretical model of the universe in physics? With every type of space and dimensions?

Answer (score -1):

Inflation was an observation, so if you meant dark energy or detecting dark matter, it's an active area of research.

If you want different laws or so to speak, the orthodox physics these days mainly concern quantum and relativity. However, there's indication that a new theory may be needed after all. I thought GR was able to explain inflation by introduce the universal factor. Anyway, thought it might help.

Comment: Quantum  theory doesn't produce different laws, a good example is schrodinger's cat, if the cat is both alive and dead and split into different universes, the same laws apply to both universes, the universe where the cat is dead and the universe where the cat is alive. Gravity etc... still exists in the same way. In each position of the superstate of particles, the eventual universe of the location would have to have the same physics laws to exist.